# Possible error in Pandas squeeze() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm a relatively new user to Pandas and have been using it to analyze BLS (Bureau of Labor Statistics) time series (downloaded from their ftp site). But I encountered a problem I have reproduced in the Python program below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

yvals1 = np.array( [10.] )
yvals2 = np.array( [10., 20.] )

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"yvals": yvals1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"yvals": yvals2})
```

The contents of the DataFrame objects `df1` and `df2` are as expected:

```
df1: 
   yvals
0   10.0

df2: 
   yvals
0   10.0
1   20.0
```

However, applying the squeeze() method gives different results for `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1.squeeze(): 
10.0

f2.squeeze(): 
0    10.0
1    20.0
Name: yvals, dtype: float64
```

As expected from the documentation, `df2.squeeze()` gives a Pandas Series object with two rows, but `df1.squeeze()` gives a scalar `numpy.float64` instead of a Panda Series object with one row. This has to be a bug and not a feature since a series with 1 row should be treated the same as any other series when one has no advance information.

I am using Python 2.7.13 and Pandas 0.20.1. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as expected. `squeeze` is eliminating a dimension if its size is `1`

So your dataframe of size `(2, 1)` gets squeezed to `(2, )` and your dataframe of size `(1, 1)` gets squeezed to a scalar.

To get your expected results, use the `axis=1` parameter

```
df1.squeeze(axis=1)

0    10.0
Name: yvals, dtype: float64
```

---

**From Tooltip**

```
Signature: df1.squeeze(axis=None)
Docstring:
Squeeze length 1 dimensions.

Parameters
----------
axis : None, integer or string axis name, optional
    The axis to squeeze if 1-sized.

    .. versionadded:: 0.20.0

Returns
-------
scalar if 1-sized, else original object
File:      //anaconda/envs/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py
Type:      method
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have realized that `squeeze()` now has an `axis` argument. It's interesting that for a single row the default `axis=None` gives a scalar but `axis=0` and `axis=1` both give Pandas Series object. Anyway, thanks again; you've given me more to think about.